# Finding all values

Tags: prolog

I'm new in world of prolog and I'm currently stuck on one problem in school project.
I have facts:

```
family (
    person(_,_,_,_), %father
    person(_,_,_,_), %mother
    []). %array with children
```

First three fields are name, surname and date_of_birth and fourth field can be either: `unemployed`, `benefit`, `employed(Name_of_company, Salary)`. I have also predicates:

```
exists(Person) % I think that implementation is irrelevant, means that person is in DB
salary(person(_,_,_,unemployed),0).
salary(person(_,_,_,benefit,500).
salary(person(_,_,_,employed(_,S)),S).
```

That's all the facts and predicates that were given as part of exercise. I want to extract a list of all salaries of people.
I tried things like:

```
findall(X,salary(_,X),L). % it doesn't search people and returns fixed 3 values

exists(Y),
findall(X,salary(Y,X),L). %however it returns value for each person instead of combined list
```

I'm all out of ideas how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry, pasted wrong line. My first try was this one, however it returns fixe 0, 500, and something like _G654

Comment: your 'database' has the wrong shape: person/4 should spot an unique key, and salary/2 should reference such key...

Comment: @novy1234 CapelliC is correct: indeed, there might be several persons with the same name and date of birth!

Comment: Ok, thanks. It wasn't me who created this one, however I'll remember it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exists(Y),
findall(X,salary(Y,X),L). 
  %however it returns value for each person 
  %instead of combined list
```

as well it should. if you want the combined list (Im assuming, person-salary list for all persons in the database), you should create a named rule to find a person's salary, and use *it* with `findall`.

But on the other hand, why have `findall` at all in the above query? It is as if you're expecting several salaries for a given person. There surely must be only one. In that case, the query should just be

```
findall( Y-X, ( exists(Y), salary(Y,X) ), L).
```

Comment: What you wrote helped, however it wasn't an answer, just a hint, so I edited it with answer